# Queue and List ADTs in Java

Tags: java, list, queue, adt

Use a List ADT to implement the Queue ADT discussed during the course. You
should only use the List ADT as a **user of ADT** while implementing this queue. Don't
use any array or linked-list to implement this queue. You are required to
implement the methods: `enqueue`, `serve`, `length` and `full`.

I don't under stand what is list if it not linked list ?
and what is a user of ADT?

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` is one of the implementations of `List` interface, like `ArrayList` or `ArrayQueue` and it already implements `Queue`, so it's excluded from the requirement. But you can use any other implementations of `List` either extend or aggregate into your `Queue` implementation.